# DAX Calculate Multiple Criteria Issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot, dax

I am having an issue with the Calculate function through PowerPivot giving me the correct numbers. Assume the following information.

```
RepairsTable

Repair ID   Location    Amount  Date
1   West    50  Aug
2   East    60  Aug
3   West    40  Sep
4   East    30  Sep
5   West    1000    Sep

MilesTable

Location    Miles   Date    Total Amt Repairs
West    100 Sep 
East    100 Aug
```

The Total Amt Repairs in the Miles Table is a calculated column in PowerPivot which I want to show the total $ amount of repairs based on Location & Date from Repairs Table.

I have used the following formulas:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(RepairsTable[Amount]),FILTER(RepairsTable,RepairsTable[Date]=MilesTable[Date]))
```

and

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(RepairsTable[Amount]),FILTER(RepairsTable,RepairsTable[Location]=MilesTable[Location]))
```

As well as:

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(RepairsTable[Amount]),FILTER(RepairsTable,RepairsTable[Date]=MilesTable[Date]&&RepairsTable[Location]=MilesTable[Location]))
```

and

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(RepairsTable[Amount]),FILTER(RepairsTable,RepairsTable[Date]=MilesTable[Date]),FILTER(RepairsTable,RepairsTable[Location]=MilesTable[Location]))
```

I can't for the life of me seem to come up with the correct values in the `Total Amt Repairs` calculated column. The values I am looking for are:

```
1040 for West/Sep
60 for East/Aug
```

I can do this just fine with a `SUMIFS` function in a spreadsheet but I can't make it work in PowerPivot.

Answer (score 0):

So, a few things to cover here.

1. Why are you changing tools if the problem is solved elsewhere?
2. Why does this aggregation need to be in a calculated column? The type of aggregation you're looking at here is typically performed in a pivot table by measures, rather than in calculated columns.
3. If, understanding the above, you're still convinced that doing this in a calculated column in the model is the right solution, your 3rd and 4th measure both work for me with your sample data, with no relation between the tables, with a relationship between each table's [Location], or with a relationship between each table's [Date].

Beyond that, the best formulation of what you want is the following:

```
=CALCULATE(
    SUM(RepairsTable[Amount])
    ,RepairsTable[Date] = EARLIER(MilesTable[Date])
    ,RepairsTable[Location] = EARLIER(MilesTable[Location])
)
```

I hesitate to suggest it, though, because it is identical to your 4th definition with two filters, just more cleanly expressed.

What is going on in your real data that differs from this sample?